# The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5X_API_22 was killed

Tags: android-emulator, emulators

I installed Android Studio with Android SDK from the offical web-site, created a new sample project, didn't change or delete even a line, but the project doesn't work anyway.

```
D:\AndSDK\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_22
Hax is enabled
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

02/11 16:19:14: Launching app
Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5X_API_22 was killed.
```

What can be wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to:  Tools > Android > AVD Manager
2. Press the "edit" (pencil) icon next to your AVD
3. Change "Graphics" to "Software".

Comment: The options is there but disabled for me in *Android Studio 4.0.1* with *Android 10.0 x86* :(

Comment: How this solved the issue, can someone explain...?

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

> emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

The emulator wasn't able to use OpenGL ES emulation on your PC. As the message says, you can disable it using the command-line, or by turning off the "Use Host GPU" option in the emulator's settings dialog, but then the emulator will be very slow. It would be better to run your app on a real phone.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me, in other places I read that is a problem with the library shipped with the SDK.

The following line worked for me

```
$ android-sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_27 -use-system-libs
```

Now you can see the device from Android Studio and connect to it. Probably exists an option inside the AVD configuration to fix this.

Comment: However, I got a PANIC from the command line that I am missing the engine for 'arm' CPU.

PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPU.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:
Go to Tools> AVD Manager > Click on downward arrow beside your emulator > Wipe data
It will confirm if you want to wipe data, say yes in that case.

Answer (score -2):

The-emulator-process-for-avd-nexus-5x-api-22-was-killed????
simple change "Nexus5XApi22" to "Nexus" problem solved.

Comment: I'm curious why changing the AVD name will fix the issue about OpenGL ES emulation?

Comment: I didn't know proper reasons but its working fine

Answer (score -2):

Since the log also mentioned

> ```
> audio: Failed to create voice 'goldfish_audio_in'
> ```

Check your Windows 10's **Privacy settings > Microphone**. If it is disabled, enable it.

Comment: Are you saying enabling microphone prevents Emulator process from being killed? How did you reach this conclusion?

Comment: i was referring to this. `audio: Failed to create voice goldfish_audio_in'`
I had the same error with this,.